# Zend framework 2 translate Image captcha messages

Tags: zend-framework2, translation, captcha, zend-form-element

I have this Image captcha thats is working correctly, but I can't get the "badCaptcha" validation error translated.

I have the key **Captcha value is wrong** translated in my .po file with PoEdit.

This is my CAPTCHA form element:

```
    $this->form->add(array(
        'name' => 'captcha',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
        'options' => array(
            'captcha' => new \Zend\Captcha\Image(array(
                'imgDir' => './public/assets/images/captcha',
                'ImgUrl' => '/assets/images/captcha',
                'width' => 330,
                'height' => 90,
                'wordlen' => 3, 
                'dotNoiseLevel' => 30,
                'lineNoiseLevel' => 3,
                'font' => './data/captcha/font/monofont.ttf',
                'fontSize' => 52,
                'expiration' => 600,
            )),
            'messages' => array(
                'badCaptcha' => $this->getTranslatorHelper()->translate('Captcha value is wrong', 'csnuser'),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

PS: $this->getTranslatorHelper() retrieves the MvcTranslator service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all wrong...ZF2 documentation in this topic is at least innacurate.

You may activate this very basic function this way:

In your Application (yes, I'm using Skeleton App) module config file (module.config.php)

```
...
...
'translator' => array(
'locale' => 'xx_XX', //Or whatever you want
'translation_file_patterns' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'gettext',
        'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
        'pattern' => '%s.mo',
    ),
    // Add this new file pattern
    array(
        'type' => 'phparray',
        //You get this translated files from vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages
        'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language/validation',
        //You may rename it to xx_XX.php for the pattern to match!
        'pattern' => '%s.php',
    ),
...
...
...
```

After that, you may create Application module onBootstrap event listener in Module.php file, like this:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    ...
    ...
    \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator'));
    ...
    ...
}
```

This way I got **Captcha value is wrong** translated!

Comment: Thanks! I spent 4 hours for this.

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 has already translate all forms messages zend_validate.php and captacha_validate.php are already translated them
you can find them here :

> vendor\zendframework\zendframework\resources\languages\fr

Copy this files into your application langage folder and call them into your config

```
'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'fr_FR',
        'translation_files' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'phpArray',
                'filename' => 'resources/languages/fr.php'
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

for example
You can have both php translation file AND po file.

EDIT :

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'fr_FR',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo', //<-%s is important
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'phpArray',
            'base_dir' => './module/Application/language/Zend_Validate/',
            'pattern'  => '%s-Zend_Validate.php',
        ),
    ),
),
```

When you have multiple lang to handle you have to load different file according to the lang choosen. %s take 'locale'.

Check if it's your problem :)

Comment: Hi, I knew about this files, but I'm wondering if it's possible to have a .po file way of doing the translation. Thanks in advise.

Comment: Well, this is pretty weird...in my Skeleton Application module, copied the spanish validation translation file, renamed it to es.php added the missing captcha translation keys from english file and then, translated it to spanish but captcha validation error message keeps english!. The es.php file is loading, because ZF2 translator is not complaining that the file can't be found.

Comment: Yes, already tryed that, in my translation_file_patterns key I have an array with: 'type'     => 'phparray', 'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language/validation/', 'pattern'     => '%s-Zend_Validate.php' but still I can't get the 'Captcha value is wrong' message translated!

Answer (score 0):

No renaming nescecary:

```
'pattern' => '%2.2s/Zend_Validate.php'
```